# How to use Facebook GraphQL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graphql

How to intercept and send HTTP requests for GraphQL?
I saw some people are able to find security bugs via GraphQL on Facebook. How do they do it?

Are there any tools available to test these calls?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook GraphQL is an internal API so I'm not sure anyone here will be able to give you a detailed answer on using it. For testing GraphQL, you will want to check to see if a public schema is available.

Starting at https://graphql.org/ or going into the spec itself http://facebook.github.io/graphql/ might be of interest to you.

If the schema is not available then you're going to have to understand how the app works, follow the requests and make assumptions (like in the case with Facebook)